# Status of QNC vs. PSPACE

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing

It is known that $\text{NC} \neq \text{PSPACE}$, now I am wondering if there is a similar separation for $\text{QNC}$, the class of decision problems solvable by polylogarithmic-depth quantum circuits with bounded error probability. That is what is the status of $\text{QNC}$ vs. $\text{PSPACE}$?